# How can I merge two pandas DataFrames sharing a column, maintaining the same number of rows and without getting duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I have two DataFrames containing 49 rows which look like this:

```
df1

NAME    AGE
Kathy   23
Mary    43
Albert  12
Joseph  48
Mike    71
...
```

```
df2

AGE    JOB
23     Tennis player
43     Doctor
12     Student
48     Lawyer
71     Retired
...
```

I would like to merge df1 and df2 on the column 'AGE', to make the final DataFrame look like this:

```
final_df

NAME    AGE  JOB
Kathy   23   Tennis player
Mary    43   Doctor
Albert  12   Student
Joseph  48   Lawyer
Mike    71   Retired
...
```

I've tried to use the `merge` function,

```
final_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="AGE", how='outer')
```

but I get 105 rows, most of which are duplicates (not all of them). I've tried

```
verbid_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['AGE'], keep='first')
```

but I still get the 105 rows with duplicates. I've also tried

```
final_df = df1.merge(df2,how='left', left_on='AGE', right_on='AGE')
```

but I got the same result (105 rows with some duplicates).

I was wondering whether there's another method to merge `df1` and `df2` avoiding duplicates.

Comment: Merging on age seems to be a bad idea, there will be several person with the same age but different jobs, how do you want to handle that? On the other side, your data seems already aligned, so what about `df1.join(df2[['JOB']])`?